# How to approach validating data based on business scenario

Tags: python, django, validation

Let's say you have a universal college application. The user inputs their information and the universal application submits the correct subset of information to each school.

What is a good approach to organizing the data validation?

For example, when a user decides to apply to `school A` you must validate that the user has input into the universal application all of the information required for `school A`.

This process is repeated for `school B`, `school C`, etc. Most of the information that must be validated is probably the same for each application, with some small differences.

Is there a library or architecture that would be optimal for setting this up? I've looked into solutions like [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/usage.html) or [Py-Good](https://github.com/kolypto/py-good) which help with the validation part, but not really the high-level approach.

In Rails, I have seen a solution called `validation contexts`. I am trying to implement this in Python (Django).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Django, it has everything you will need to validate incoming data. The standard way to validate data with Django is through [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) (and more specifically, [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/).)

From the docs:

> Django’s role in forms
>
> Handling forms is a complex business. Consider Django’s admin, where
>   numerous items of data of several different types may need to be
>   prepared for display in a form, rendered as HTML, edited using a
>   convenient interface, returned to the server, validated and cleaned
>   up, and then saved or passed on for further processing.
>
> Django’s form functionality can simplify and automate vast portions of
>   this work, and can also do it more securely than most programmers
>   would be able to do in code they wrote themselves.

You will find some helpful examples in the links that I've posted. I would recommend looking at the `clean` method.

If the logic is mostly the same for each scenario, but with slight differences, you will likely be able to create a single form that can process the data appropriately based on what the user has selected.

Hope this helps.